# Ubuntu 15.04 Doesn't Detect Monitor - xrandr crashes

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel, xrandr

Ubuntu 15.04 doesn't automatically recognise my monitor. It does not show up in display settings. This is the same as in 14.10 (and I have done a clean install). Apart from this xrandr just freezes everything if I try to output to the monitor.

If I boot my laptop into windows then I can use the monitor just fine and I have checked with someone else who has the exact same laptop as me (and Ubuntu 15.04) and they can use my monitor (same cables and everything). I briefly managed to get it to work by disabling the intel microcode drivers in the additional software settings but this has stopped working.

I have no idea where to even begin troubleshooting this.

Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S1
Intel i7-4500U (with integrated graphics)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: An help at all? How do I find out why xrandr freezes my system? I have since found out that audio will continue to play but the system is still completely unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing similar issues. I have noticed that this occurs if I use xrandr's `--auto` option or set mode to resolution other than that set in "display" settings panel before configuring xrandr.

I am using a startup script to set xrandr when I log in:
 `xrandr --output VGA-0 --left-of DVI-0`

try replacing "VGA-0" and "DVI-0" with whatever your hardware's output'sa are.

It's not ideal, as im working at a display far smaller than my main monitor is capable of (which seems to be an unrelated issue) but I can at least use both monitors this way

Comment: can you explain a bit more how to configure xrandr?